# How to set a variable which contains other variables that will change in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, var

```
var1=0
var=$var1
(Some conditions that may change $var1)
var1=1
echo $var
```

I need to have `1` as output of `echo $var`. In other words, I need to get a new value if the variable1 contained in variable if it change.
Are there some special options or quotes that will allow me to do that?

EDIT:

```
FILE=ArchLinuxARM-$DATE-$TARGET.img
DATE=2015.10
TARGET=rpi-2

echo ${!FILE}
```

Will echo nothing. (It should echo `ArchLinuxARM-2015.10-rpi-2.img`)

Comment: So you're looking for `var` to hold a reference to `var1`?

Comment: No.  Bash "variables" are expandable names.  There's no such thing as a reference or pointer.  If you need to expand some variable in a don't-repeat-yourself manner, you can consider writing a [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) to do this.

Comment: Oops, I think with Bash, you can.  I was mistaking sh with Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific question, you'd be better served with a function:

```
filename() { echo "ArchLinuxARM-$DATE-$TARGET.img"; }

DATE=2015.10
TARGET=rpi-2

echo "$(filename)"
```

Comment: This one did the trick, and can be used same way as variable.

Comment: Also consider `filename(){ echo "ArchLinuxARM-"$1"-"$2".img"; }` to avoid the use of globals.

Comment: That just makes the function invocations noisier, and defeats the ease that the OP is seeking.

Answer (score 0):

In bash **version 4.3**, you can create reference variables:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.42(1)-release
$ declare -n var=var1
$ var1=0; echo $var
0
$ var1=1; echo $var
1
```